# How to build a sample Ogre / Xcode template for iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ogre, xcode-template

Hi 
I have installed Ogre 1.7 , Copied iphone dependencies and the project is running in simulator with around 25 sample projects. I need to build a template with only one sample example. Can you please guide me to do so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions for running Ogre on iPhone: http://ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Ogre+iPhone&structure=Development

To run basic Ogre project rather than all samples

- Install Ogre SDK for iPhone
- Add Ogre iOS dependencies to SDK folder: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogre/files/ogre-dependencies-mac/1.7/
- Download and install XCode templates
- Create new project using Ogre template (ensure that _OGRESDK_ROOT_ points to Ogre SDK)

Works for me.